# Where should I ask a question about where should I ask a question?

Tags: support, questions, meta

I have a question and I'm not sure which site it should be asked on (or perhaps SE doesn't *have* a site for it).

Where should I ask about where should I ask it? Here? Area 51? Somewhere else altogether?

As an example, the question in question is where should I ask a question about phones, not pertaining to a specific OS?

If this is not the right place to ask *this* question, please let me know. This is my first meta question.

Comment: Here. See a [few examples](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation?sort=votes&pageSize=50) under the [tag:site-recommendation] tag.

Comment: @gnat I couldn't find that one. Thanks!

Comment: Here, or on any other meta.

Comment: Where should I ask a question asking about about people asking about asking a question?